# Emulate Windows C-Del/C-Backspace behavior in VIM

Tags: windows, vim, behavior

I like to emulate the normal behavior of C-Del/C-Backspace on Windows in VIM.
Currently i'm using:

```
imap <C-Del> <C-o>dw
imap <C-Backspace> <C-o>db
```

This is close but not perfect. E.g. when trying to delete this from the end of the line

```
foo(1, 2)
```

with C-Backspace, this happens:

```
foo(1, )
```

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

your new `<C-Backspace>` is the same as internal `<C-w>`. So to solve your problem you can

```
imap <C-Backspace> <C-w>
```